# regex to skip part of string if it contain a specific word

Tags: regex

I need to retrieve uri from string in a named capture group

Example uri's are,

```
/cu/rest/en_US/reports/execute/310F02501000016D001218A1AZ6B2D16
/cu/rest/en_US/reports/execute/newResource/
/cu/rest/en_US/link/xml
```

If the string contain 'execute' in it, regex should skip characters that appear after 'execute', otherwise it should match whole uri in given string

And the regex I am currently using is,

```
(?P<value>\S+)
```

this matches whole uri into 'value' even if contain 'execute' in it.

is it possible to have conditional regex based on which 'value' will be set to either contain whole uri or skip some part of it?

For 3 example above, 'value' should be

1. /cu/rest/en_US/reports/execute
2. /cu/rest/en_US/reports/execute
3. /cu/rest/en_US/link/xml

Comment: Try `^(?P<value>\S+?(?:/execute(?![^/])|$))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?P<value>\S*?(?:/execute(?![^/])|$))
```

Or, with a tempered greedy token:

```
^(?P<value>(?:(?!/execute/)\S)*)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/MwEwHH/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/MwEwHH/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<value>\S*?(?:/execute(?![^/])|$))` - Group "value":

  - `\S*?` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars, as few as possible
  - `(?:/execute(?![^/])|$)`  - a non-capturing group matching

    - `/execute(?![^/])` - a `/execute` substring followed with `/` or end of string (note that `(?![^/])` = `(?=/|$)`, but is slightly more efficient since contains no alternation and takes just 1 step)
    - `|` - or
    - `$` - end of string.

The `(?:(?!/execute/)\S)*` just matches any non-whitespace char (`\S`), 0 or more occurrences (`*`), that does not start the `/execute/` char sequence. Note that in case you should ba all means check for a slash or end of string after `/execute`, use `/execute(?![^/])` instead of `/execute/`.

Comment: I am not able to use this regex in my complete string, (I avoided posting whole string to not make question complex)
I modified your regex to add \S* at the end to match first 2 examples, but I am not able to make it match 3rd example,

https://regex101.com/r/2PmsWv/4
Could you help me with it?

Comment: @Sandeep Probably it will be easier to use a tempered greedy token here: `(?P<value>(?:(?!/execute)\S)*)\S*`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PmsWv/5).